# Resolving inconsistent sub/superscript behavior with newpxmath and certain delimiters

Tags: math-mode, fonts

**Edit:** I reached out to the package maintainer and he very quickly patched the issue. As of `newpx` version 1.410 (released 2/15/20), the issue should be resolved.

---

I recently started using `newpxmath` which I quite like, but it seems to have an issue aligning a superscript and subscript in certain circumstances.

The following example, without `newpxmath`, works fine and after every pair of delimiters, we see proper alignment between the subscript 2 and the superscript 2.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\vec{x}^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

$(\vec{x})^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

$\left(\vec{x}\right)^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

$\left\lVert\vec{x}\right\rVert^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

Fixed: $|\vec{x}|^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

Fixed: $\lVert \vec{x}\rVert^2_2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, after switching to `newpxmath`, the last two examples are slightly off, with the superscript 2 being slightly to the right of the subscript 2:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$\vec{x}^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

$(\vec{x})^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

$\left(\vec{x}\right)^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

$\left\lVert\vec{x}\right\rVert^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

Bad: $|\vec{x}|^2_2$
\vspace{2mm}

Bad: $\lVert \vec{x}\rVert^2_2$

\end{document}
```

[image: newpxmath behavior]

Is this a bug in `newpxmath`, or am I misunderstanding the expected behavior, and either way is there a workaround?

Comment: Remember that the `minimal` class is not meant for MWEs (confusingly enough, it is used for some internal testing, and may not setup some stuff that packages need). Might be better to use `article` or similar.

Comment: The difference is definitely there with `\}`, `\rvert` and `\rVert`. I believe you should better contact the maintainer (Michael Sharpe). He's the only one who can tell if this is the intended behaviour or not.

Comment: @campa: I sent him an email and he immediately got back saying he'd publish an update soon !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here there is my MWE with the correct sub/superscripts.

**EDITS: By correct comments of the users.**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\[\vec{x}^2_2\]

\[(\vec{x})^2_2\]

\[\left(\vec{x}\right)^2_2\]

\[\left\lVert\vec{x}\right\rVert^2_2\]

\[\textbf{Improved brackets}\quad |\vec{x}|{^{2}_{2}}, \quad \lVert \vec{x}\rVert{^{2}_{2}}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: While the hack apparently solves the issue, I would never refer to this as "use correctly the brackets" (=braces).

Comment: @campa Ok. I agree with you..excuse me.

Comment: Remember it is never a good idea to use the `minimal` class for MWEs

Comment: @daleif I have just copied by the MWE of the user. Now edit my answer.

Comment: I sometimes do it a little differently `\newcommand\dvec[1]{\smash{\vec{#1}}\vphantom{#1}}` then left/right never sees the vector arrow

Comment: @daleif You're always welcome. You can edit my answer and to add your code or if you prefer I delete my answer. No problem. My best regards.